# usage of service layer classes as composition rather than inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have been to told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379969/asp-net-mvc-layered-application-am-i-understanding-it-right) that I should separate my `Service` class and `Repository` class, so I did. And below is an example.

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetCurrentProductsOnOrderForCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

But how do I use this in my `Controller`? How I use it is like this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  ProductService prodService = new ProductService();
}
```

But I've read that should implement abstraction. Should I make another class called `IProductService` and use it like this?

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  private readonly IProductService  _productService;
  private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

  public ProductController(IProductService  productService, IUnitOfWork uow)
  {
    _uow = uow;
    _productService = productService;
  }
}
```

An example of `IProductService` would be great. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the idea is to inject UoW into Service so you don't have it on the controller and the constructor should be something like: ProductController(IProductService service) and ProductService(IUow uow). Keep in mind that UoW when using EF *may* not a very good option.

Comment: @Bart Hi. Thanks mate. Think you put it in the answer section with code? And why UoW is not a very good option with EF. I would like to hear some thoughts. Thanks. You see I'm new in the field.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I will point to a good article about my concerns of EF and UOW. There are more, but this is a good first lookup if you are interested: http://tech.pro/blog/1191/say-no-to-the-repository-pattern-in-your-dal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your different layers like this:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IProductRepository productRepository;

    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetCurrentProductsOnOrderForCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

So the controller layer should do this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
     private readonly IProductService prodService;

     public ProductController(IProductService prodService)
     {
         this.prodService = prodService;
     }
}
```

And your webapp layer, should use Dependency Injection to fill the different constructors. Or you can do it manually in case of a small business domain.

Comment: Thanks mate. One request, think you can help me with this I asked. Been banging my head with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425263/applying-unit-of-work-in-a-generic-repository